# find orphan veths on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, networking, bash, linux-networking

i use a system that adds ips, netns and veth's via script and deletes them if no longer needed. I was using centos 7 but i decided to switch to ubunutu. it seems that on ubuntu orphanded veths are not deleted. so i need a way to delete them by script. i figured out that orphand veths can be identified via "**ip link show**". They dont have valid IP shown. I now need a way to grep with this command and get all vethXXX with no valid ip and deleted them via:

```
ip link set down $link
ip link delete $link
```

This is how a valid veth looks:

```
190: veth0@if189: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:2f:93:b8:b9:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns 62.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

This is how a orphand veth looks:

```
188: veth0@if187: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:4f:37:88:7d:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 27
```

Comment: It depends on your scripts. the link-netns information is not an IP address, it's a string set by your script and used as name for `ip netns` and you chose this string to look like an IP address. If a resource use (eg a process) keeps the namespace (netns) existing when you issue `ip netns del` then the name (but not the namespace) disappears and `ip link` won't resolve the netnsid into a netns with its associated name anymore. You should find what keeps the netns around.

Comment: You can install and use plotnetcfg to diagnose what are the processes (or other objects) keeping the namespace alive.